# IE not rendering primeng p-table correctly

Tags: angular

I have a primeng p-table component. The table displays fine in Chrome and Firefox but only spans across about half of the page in IE.

I just included the p-table element without content.

```
<p-card>
<p-table #subsTable
           [value]="subs"
           sortMode="multiple"
           selectionMode="single"
           (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
           (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)"
           [(selection)]="selectedSub"
           [columns]="columns"
           dataKey="subId"
           [paginator]="subs.length > 0"
           (onPage)="onPageChange($event)"
           [rows]="5"
           >
    </p-table>
    </p-card>
```

css:

```
.ui-table table {
    table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

The issue is that `table-layout: fixed;` is being inherited from primeng on the `.ui-table table` css block. I tried overwriting that with my own css as you see but that did not work. I also ran the 3 npm commands in polyfills.ts (`npm install --save classlist.js`, `npm install --save web-animations-js`, and `npm install --save intl`).

How can I overwrite/fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
::ng-deep .ui-table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will fix it**

```
const trs = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ui-table-scrollable-body-table tbody tr");
        
        if (trs && trs.length) {
          const tr = trs[0];
          const tds = tr.querySelectorAll("td")
          if (tds && tds.length) {
            tds[tds.length - 1].style.width = "101%";
            setTimeout(function () {
              tds[tds.length - 1].style.width = "100%";
            }, 10)
          }
        }
      }, 50);
```